# Translating a "flat" list to nested HTML unordered lists

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a list of items to work with in a Django template. Each item has a name and a category. The category can be separated with slashes to create sub-categories. I need to turn the flat list into a nested unordered HTML list. What is the best way to do this? Modifying the data structure with Python in the Django view is an option, but I would prefer to do this within Django's template rendering. JavaScript is also an option to solve this.

The list is guaranteed to be ordered properly because of the way I query the items from the database.

For example, given the Python structure:

```
[
    { category: 'Food/Fruits', name: 'Apple' },
    { category: 'Food/Fruits', name: 'Banana' },
    { category: 'Food/Fruits', name: 'Coconut' },
    { category: 'Food/Meats', name: 'Steak' },
    { category: 'Food/Meats', name: 'Chicken' },
    { category: 'Furniture', name: 'Chair' },
]
```

I want to create nested lists out of these items. This would turn into:

```
<label>Food</label>
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Fruits
        <ul>
            <li>Apple</li>
            <li>Banana</li>
            <li>Coconut</li>
        </ul>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Meats
        <ul>
            <li>Steak</li>
            <li>Chicken</li>
        </ul>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
</label>
<label>Furniture</label>
<ul>
    <li>Chair</li>
</ul>
</label>
```

The rendered result would look like this:

Food

- Fruits

  - Apple
  - Banana
  - Coconut
- Meats

  - Steak
  - Chicken

Furniture

- Chair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag:

```
<label>Food</label>
{% regroup foods by category as category_list %}
<ul>
{% for category in category_list %}
    <li>
        <label>{{ category.grouper }}</label>
        <ul>
        {% for food in category.list %}
            <li>{{ food.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the *exact* use case for regroup.